# Combining these functions to make a character move in a dynamic matrix in C

Tags: c, linux, matrix

Hi there I'm new at C on linux and as a school project I have to make a game of car racing with a top down view, like OutRun but more simplistic. The game should run on the linux terminal because I'm not in the mood of learning C and SDL at the same time. 
As for the project, what I'm planning to do is drawing the road with a dynamic matrix of full of zeros and when I press right a car(taken by the twitter emoticons) will exchange values with the case next to it, however I don't know how to do it properly, I've looked for a function called ncurses that create a new window and let you to move the cursor, a function that creates, fill and exchange a value from a matrix, and a function that let you move the cursor from left to right on the terminal.

OPENS A NEW WINDOW

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int ch, c;
    initscr ();
    cbreak ();
    noecho ();
    while (ch != 'q') {
        switch (c = getch ()) {
        case 'a':
            ch = 'b';
            break;

        case 'b':
            ch = 'c';
            break;

        case 'c':
            ch = 'd';
            break;

        default:
            ch = c;
            break;
        }
        printw ("%c", ch);
    }
    endwin ();
    return (0);
}
```

CREATES "MOVABLE" CURSOR AND THE CAR

```
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define KEY_ESCAPE  0x001b
#define KEY_ENTER   0x000a
#define KEY_UP      0x0105
#define KEY_DOWN    0x0106
#define KEY_LEFT    0x0107
#define KEY_RIGHT   0x0108

typedef struct carro CARRO;

struct carro {
    int posx;
    int posy;
    char alignement;
    char type;
    char colour[10];
    char custom[30];
    char etat;
};

char key_pressed ()
{
    struct termios oldterm, newterm;
    int oldfd;
    char c, result = 0;

    tcgetattr (STDIN_FILENO, &oldterm);
    newterm = oldterm;
    newterm.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr (STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newterm);
    oldfd = fcntl (STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl (STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldfd | O_NONBLOCK);

    c = getchar ();

    tcsetattr (STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldterm);
    fcntl (STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldfd);
    if (c != EOF) {
        ungetc (c, stdin);
        result = getchar ();
    }

    return result;
}

int main () {

    char c;
    c = key_pressed ();
    printf ("%c", c);

    return 0;
}
```

CREATES DYNAMIC MATRIX AND PERMUTES TWO INTEGERS

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **allocation_mat_dyn (int nb_l, int nb_c)
{
    int **mat = malloc (nb_l * sizeof (int *));
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < nb_l; i++) {
        mat[i] = malloc (nb_c * sizeof (int));
    }
    return mat;
}

void chargement_mat (int nb_l, int nb_c, int **mat)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < nb_l; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nb_c; j++) {
            scanf ("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void affichage_mat (int nb_l, int nb_c, int **mat)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < nb_l; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nb_c; j++) {
            printf ("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}

void mat_changement_pos (int nb_l, int nb_c, int **matrice)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    matrice[34][21] = matrice[34][22];
    matrice[34][22] = tmp;
}

void affichage_mat_ext (int nb_l, int nb_c, int **mat)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < nb_l; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nb_c; j++) {
            if (j > 20) {
                printf ("%d ", mat[i][j]);
            } else {
                printf ("  ");

            }
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}

void lib_mat (int nb_l, int **mat)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < nb_l; i++) {
        free (mat[i]);
    }
}

int main () {

    int n, **mat;
    int m;

    scanf ("%d %d\n", &n, &m);
    mat = allocation_mat_dyn (n, m);
    chargement_mat (n, m, mat);
    affichage_mat_ext (n, m, mat);
    printf ("\n");
    mat_changement_pos (n, m, mat);
    affichage_mat_ext (n, m, mat);
    lib_mat (n, mat);
    free (mat);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help on how can I solve it or how would you do it will be apreciatted.

Comment: Minor: use `int c` in `key_pressed()` for proper `EOF` comparison.  {Aside from formatting (find an auto-formatter), nice first post}.